# Appium will report an exception when running for a long time

Tags: appium

Recently I was learning appium, I encountered a problem, appium does not seem to be very stable，
It is doing a repetitive action. When it repeats a certain number of times, it will throw an exception, but this does not seem to be a problem. Please help me, thank you very much.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes !! This is a probem with appium , we have encountered exceptions in appium version 1.7.1 when appium is kept running for a long time

**Alternatives :**

**1. Upgrade to latest appium version 1.10.0:**

The latest appium version seems to be more stable in terms of  crashing of appium in long runs, However, This version is far less stable then 1.7.1 in terms of device compatibility. 
for example if your Samsung S5 device works fine in 1.7.1 , you may encounter some errors in 1.10.0

**2. Reboot your devices**

The other options we have is to reboot the devices after certain intevral of time , i.e. after 1 hour . This will avoid crashing of appium

Comment: You are very powerful, verified, indeed, as you said, the latest version of appium is stable, your solution is very useful, thank you again